# Can the MONTH() function be used within a SUMIFS formula in Excel?

Tags: excel, sumifs

I'm trying to create a sumifs formula in excel where I am trying to compute:

Sum hours

> where 'Project' = selected project
>   and 'Assignee' = selected assignee 
>   and month of 'Due' = current month

The forumla I was trying to use for the highlighted cell was:

=SUMIFS(E3:E7,B3:B7,B13,C3:C7,C12,MONTH(D3:D7),MONTH(NOW()))

But it throws errors.

[image]

Comment: The value of D3 equals "Due", is it possible that you have mistaken for a row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not - but you might be able to trick it slightly. If you use a date in a `SUMIFS` criteria Excel does seem to be able to identify it correctly, so you can use this to define the min and max date for the values you wish to return, like so:

```
=SUMIFS($E$3:$E$7,$B$3:$B$7,$B13,$C$3:$C$7,C$12,$D$3:$D$7,">="&DATE(YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(NOW()),1),$D$3:$D$7,"<"&DATE(YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(NOW())+1,1))
```

This applies the `SUMIFS` between the 1st of the current month and the 1st of the next month.

Comment: `=SUMIFS($E$3:$E$7,$B$3:$B$7,$B13,$C$3:$C$7,C$12,$D$3:$D$7,">="&DATE(YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(NOW()),1),$D$3:$D$7,"<"&DATE(YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(NOW())+1,1))` enables you to drag the formula around.

Comment: Hadn't even noticed that in the original - thanks Robin!

Comment: Nice. Works even if month(now()) is 12, Excel handles it correctly. +1